# Position absolute div (with variable height) above the content

Tags: jquery, css

Please take a look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/am2dR/7/):

The .pos_absolute div is under the .content div, but using CSS I have made id display on top.

The problem is that in my scenario I know the **height of the .pos_absolute div** and I can **set the margin-top for the .content div**.

What can I do when the .pos_absolute div's height varies?
Is there a CSS fix? Or do I need to use jquery?
Any ideas?

Comment: just set it to relative and invert positions in HTML. Is there any specific reason for setting it to absolute? The height will vary dynamically?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/am2dR/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this using JQuery.

​Refer this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/am2dR/11/)**

### JQuery:

```
$('.pos_absolute').css('top', 0);
var tempHeight = $('.pos_absolute').height();
$('.content').css('margin-top', (tempHeight+2)+"px");
```

### CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color:#FF2E2E;
}
.pos_absolute {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF
}
​
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    Content div <br/>
    Content div <br/>
    Content div <br/>
    Content div <br/>
    Content div <br/>
</div>
<div class="pos_absolute">
    Pos absolute div <br/>
    Pos absolute div <br/>
    Pos absolute div <br/>
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jQuery:

```
$(".content").css("marginTop", $(".pos_absolute").height() + 32 +"px");
```

Comment: oh, it's just a number I used to test, you can change it to any number you need

Comment: i mean it will serve as the margin between the two divs?

Comment: because you cannot get "em" using jQuery(at least no straight forward method), so I use "px" here